# Unable to parse Contents of Structure in the code

Tags: c, list, struct

I am trying to accumulate all types of list in a Structure and refer to each from that structure rather than using different name of the structure

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #define TRUE 1
    #define FALSE 0

    typedef struct test_s {
        int    val;
        int     p;
    }test_t;

    test_t list_1[] = {
            { TRUE, 1},
            { TRUE, 2},
            { TRUE, 3}
    };

    test_t  list_2[] = {
            {FALSE, 1},
            {TRUE , 2},
            {TRUE , 3}
    };

    test_t list_types[][] = { list_1, list_2 };
    test_t *list = NULL;

    void
    main() {

        list = list_types[0];

        int iter = 0;
        for ( iter = 0; iter < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); iter++){
            printf("Bool: %d Val: %d\n",list[0].val, list[0].p);
        }
    }
```

I am 
When I am trying to compile, I am getting following error. Please highlight what I am missing in this snippet

```
test.c:22:8: error: array type has incomplete element type
```

Comment: I changed `test_t list_types[][] = { list_1, list_2 };` then the error is ` error: array type has incomplete element type
`

Comment: Change `test_t list_types[][] = { list_1, list_2 };` to `test_t *list_types[] = { list_1, list_2 };` and you will have it.  See edits in my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

*EDIT* to answer your question about initialization:
As I mentioned in my comment under your post, the initialization of your 'list_types` variable is not correct.

Using your original version of the `list_types` variable:

```
test_t **list_types = { list_1, list_2 };
```

My compiler throws error:

> `Invalid initialization type;found`pointer to test_t`expected`
>   pointer to pointer to test_t

Using this version (that was edited in later):

```
test_t list_types[][] = { list_1, list_2 };
```

My compiler throws error:

> Missing array size for higher dimensions of multidimensional array.

Neither of those initialization will work.  Change the form of your initialization to:

```
test_t *list_types[] = { list_1, list_2 };
```

and it will throw no errors, and contain both instances of `test_t.

*END* of edit.

*...refer to each from that structure rather than using different name...*

With the initialization made as shown above, you can now refer to each structure using the same name as shown below:

```
....
//test_t **list_types = { list_1, list_2 };//incorrect initialization...
test_t *list = NULL;

void main(void) {

    list = &list_1[0]; //assign list_1 to list

    int iter = 0;
    for ( iter = 0; iter < 3; iter++){
        printf("Bool: %d Val: %d\n",list[iter].val, list[iter].p);
    }


    list = &list_2[0];//assign list_2 to list

    iter = 0;
    for ( iter = 0; iter < 3; iter++){
        printf("Bool: %d Val: %d\n",list[iter].val, list[iter].p);
    }
    getchar();//stops execution in my environment
}
```

The following illustrates contents of the `list` instance:

After first assignment:

[image]

After second assignment:

[image]

Comment: I don't think malloc is necessary in this case...Memory is statically allocated.. I am just referring that memory .. this code doesn't solve my original question..where I want to refer list types from another structure not directly

Comment: See edits.  1st section assigns `list` to `list_1`, then to `list_2`.  No `malloc(...)` used.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you want to create an array of struct-pointer.

**Step 1** - declare and initialize the array as using.

```
test_t *list_types[] = { list_1, list_2 };
```

instead  of:

```
test_t list_types[][] = { list_1, list_2 };
```

**Step 2** - use that array instead of a pointer to that array to now the size.

> And use the index `iter` to select between `list_1` or `list_2`,
>   otherwise you will access to the `list_1`.
>
> To access to all items of one `list_<x>`, it is necessary to store the
>   size.

```
for ( iter = 0; iter < sizeof(list_types)/sizeof(list_types[0]); iter++){
    list = list_types[iter];
    printf("Bool: %d Val: %d\n",list[0].val, list[0].p);
}
```

instead of:

```
for ( iter = 0; iter < sizeof(list)/sizeof(list[0]); iter++){
    printf("Bool: %d Val: %d\n",list[0].val, list[0].p);
}
```